# How to calculate probability for new person from existing logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, credit-scoring

I need to create a credit scorecard model. Once I ran a logistic regression to find out the probability of default of a customer, how do I calculate scores of new customers? I have variables like age, debt to income ratio, amount of credit card debt, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the logistic coefficients, take their natural log to get back to the index function scale from the odds ratio scale, and multiply them by the values of the covariates, sum the products, and evaluate the cumulative logistic distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$ of that sum.

Here's an example in Stata for one observation. First we fit the model:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. logistic foreign mpg weight

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =         74
                                                LR chi2(2)        =      35.72
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -27.175156                     Pseudo R2         =     0.3966

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |   .8448578   .0776572    -1.83   0.067     .7055753    1.011635
      weight |   .9961009   .0010077    -3.86   0.000     .9941279    .9980779
       _cons |   898396.7    4059594     3.03   0.002     127.9781    6.31e+09
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Let's predict $\Pr(foreign=1)$ for the estimation sample:

```
. predict phat
(option pr assumed; Pr(foreign))
```

Let's peek at the first observation:

```
. list mpg foreign phat mpg weight in 1, clean noobs

    mpg    foreign       phat   mpg   weight  
     22   Domestic   .1904363    22    2,930
```

Let's match that by hand:

```
. display logistic(ln(898396.7) + ln(.8448578)*22 + ln(.9961009)*2930)
.1904268
```

You can see that the manual predicted probability matches the the output of Stata's predict command (the phat variable I defined) pretty closely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really.

Logistic regression is typically intended to model discrete outcomes, like being dead or alive, sick or well, or account in good standing/default. You, however, want to predict a continuous value (in [280, 850] or [501, 990] or whatever).

You could get the probability of default out of a logistic regression model, but that alone is typically just one component of a credit score. You could potentially plug that value, along with other predictors, into a regression model to predict a credit score.

Strictly speaking, I'm not even sure if credit scoring systems are actually regression models. There may just be some proprietary algorithm that combines the information to produce a single value using ad-hoc weights.

Comment: The output from a logistic regression doesn't have to be discrete: the model gives a probability in [0, 1]. You could simply define a person's credit score to be that probability...

Comment: ...and possibly scale it to live in [200,900], if that's desired.

Comment: True, that was pretty sloppy (edited to fix). Still, I think credit scores are a bit more than P(default) * scale

Comment: I think the claim that logistic regression is classification and *not* regression is overstated - to the point of being a mischaracterization. It's perfectly possible  (e.g. in an experiment), for example, to have a set of binomial responses  at *each* value of x, and the model for the mean (as for a binomial response) is simply for $p$, the proportion of successes at each $x$. Meanwhile $p$ might remain - for every $x$ under consideration - between 0.25 and 0.4, say. Where's the *classification* in this model for a binomial proportion?

Comment: @Glen_b, I suppose that's fair. However, wouldn't you agree that logistic regression is not going to produce an arbitrary continuous value on its own?

Comment: I don't think I agree. If the aim is to find an estimate of the "probability of default" for new customers (which is what the title says), the logistic regression can certainly do that. Given the title, I assume 'score' is intended either to be that probability (or perhaps to be some monotonic function of it, such as the linear predictor in the logistic regression), but in either case, that can be done with logistic regression.

Comment: My impression was that the poster already has calculated the probability of default with a logistic model, but now wants to turn it into a [credit score](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_score), which, at least in North America, is some numeric value that includes P(Default) along with some other factors